# Melted Headlight Socket for H11 bulb

Tags: electrical, headlight, bulbs

I recently discovered a low beam headlight socket had melted on the passenger side of my **2005 Volvo XC90**. Several days back I had this `Bulb Failure Low Beam` message showing up and going away. When I went to inspect the light being emitted from the bulb each time I found both sides to be illuminated and just thought that maybe the bulb was going out and that it was going to imminently fail.

Then after perhaps 2 or three other instances of that same message reoccurring the bulb actually did go out. When I opened the headlight lens to replace the bulb instead I found a melted connector like shown in the photos below. Only one half had melted away, and this white soot substance was also left behind. The melted plastic had dribbled down the terminal and began to pool out where the wire connected to the body of the plastic socket on the harness.

I measured the resistance of the bulb, it measured 0.5 Ohms, and also showed continuity.

After I replace the wiring harness what are some inspection points I should look to and keep an eye out for so this failure doesn't repeat. I expect this to be a one time fluke, is that a reasonable expectation? If it should reoccur what am I to make of the faulty electronics involved?

[image: melted low beam socket image with flash]

[image: melted low beam socket image no flash]

[image: bulb connected to melted socket side by side flash, no flash]

[image: Volvo bulb failure message]

Comment: Linking to a very similar question for a different style bulb https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/39419/causes-of-melted-connector-on-h4-lamp-for-headlight

Comment: Loose connection as mentioned in one answer in the duplicate: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/39419/10976

Comment: Looks like the 55W bulb idea put in that other answer may be the culprit. I need to look up some reference material for the Volvo specs on that bulb connector and what the expected wattage is. Duplicate is a good move here though.